# if any(): Store an element from a list that has been found within a string into a variable

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 2 columns. I search for elements of an array within the  column TXT (works already) but I don't know how to write the element I found into the variable value.

E.g. In the first row df.TXT is '30m AB'. 'AB' is an element of list l. Variable value should be 'AB'.

```
| Number | TXT    |
|--------|--------|
| 1234   | 30m AB |
| 2345   | BLA    |
| 3456   | 50g EF |
| 4567   | 1GH    |
```

My Coding:

Creating data frame and array list:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Number", "TXT"], data=[[1234,'30m AB'],[2345,'BLA'],[3456,'50g EF'],[4567,'1GH']])
l = ['AB','CD','EF','GH']
```

Define function to search for elements in string of the current row:

```
def fun(row):    
    value = ''
    string = row.TXT

    if any(s in string for s in l):
        value =   # value should be the element of l found in string        
    return value
```

for-loop to run funtion for each row of df:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():    
    value = fun(row)
    df.set_value(i,'Value',value)
```

If you have any idea how to get the correct element of the list into value, please help.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: value should contain the element that the function finds.

Comment: what happen if 50 and AB are in the list??

Comment: Or what happens when 30 and AB are in the list? Which value is returned?

Comment: usually there is a whitespace before the right element if there are multiple once. Eg. '50m AB' -> value = 'AB' and 'AB1 EF' -> value = 'EF' and '1GH' -> value = 'GH'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you correct, try this(read comments, there are important points):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=["Number", "TXT"],
    data=[
        [1234,'30m AB'],
        [2345, 'BLA'],
        [3456, '50g EF'],
        [4567, '1GH'],
        [9087, 'AB1 EF'],
        [9088, ' AB 1 EF '],
]
)

items = ['AB','CD','EF','GH']

# create a new column
df['Value'] = None

# insert items to the column 'Value'
for idx, row  in df.iterrows():
    for item in items:
        if row['TXT'].strip().endswith(item):
            df.at[idx, 'Value'] = item

print df
```

**Output**

```
   Number        TXT Value
0    1234     30m AB    AB
1    2345        BLA  None
2    3456     50g EF    EF
3    4567        1GH    GH
4    9087     AB1 EF    EF
5    9088   AB 1 EF     EF
```

Comment: Great idea, thanks. Only issue is that it takes the first one in a string now. So if I have 'AB1 EF' it picks 'AB' instead of 'EF'. Any idea how to change that?

Comment: that's why you need to clarify your requirements.

Comment: Thank you so much, works perfectly! I'm sorry I have not been clear in first place. This has been my first post and I promise to work on that.